# Why does Github say that the Bitcoin project is 74% TypeScript?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

For the [Bitcoin project on Github](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) clicking "Show language statistics" shows that the source code is almost 74% TypeScript. Why is this so when ostensibly Bitcoin is written almost entirely in C++. Even Script, Bitcoin's programming language, has got nothing to do with TypeScript or Javascript. What am I missing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

That's because of the QT translation files, see https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/search?l=typescript

I'm not sure why they are recognized as TypeScript (it's just XML), I guess it's because of the filename extension `.ts`.

Comment: That's right, Github only looks at the sizes of files with specific extensions.